# Remove a character when between two numbers (regular expression)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a date with weeks using this format:

`2012-15 - 2012-20`

I want to format it to look like

`2012 v15 - 2012 v20`

How can this be done c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
        String str = "2012-15 - 2012-20";
        String newStr = Regex.Replace(str, "(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "$1 v$2");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(newStr);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Prints Out:

> 2012-15 - 2012-20
>
> 2012 v15 - 2012 v20

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string input = "2012-15 - 2012-20";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d{4})-(\d+)", "$1 v$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "2012-15 - 2012-20";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(-)\b", "v");
```